# How to duplicate Sum(Sum(Fields!VarName.Value)) using Lookupsets and Custom Code in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am fairly new to SSRS but am having a problem double summing when using `Lookupsets` as output. I have the following table and query which does work

```
Query for Hours_DataSet
         SELECT        CallbackDate, SUM(TelemarketingHours) AS DailyHours,
            (SELECT        SUM(TelemarketingHours) AS Expr1
             FROM            CallbackTbl) AS HoursPTD
         FROM            CallbackTbl AS CallbackTbl_1
         GROUP BY CallbackDate
```

Definition of Matrix

```
      |       [CallbackDate]    |    Weekly totals          
________________________________________________________________

Hours |       [Sum(DailyHours]) |  Sum(Sum(DailyHours))
```

The output is this:

```
12/01/2014 | 12/02/2014 | 12/03/2014 | 12/04/2014 | 12/05/2014| Weekly totals|

28.75      | 42         | 42.25      | 40.25      | 37.50     | 190.75
```

In another table I need to calculate the appointments per hour and total appointments per hour for the week. So I set the main data-set to be the number of appointments and use `lookupset` and custom code to do the summing.

Everything works well for one level of sum. I need to recreate the 190.75 number and use it in the as the denominator in the calculation for number of appointments per hour for the week.

```
Query for Positive_DataSet:
        SELECT  MainHistory_1.REALDATE, StatusTbl.Status, COUNT                    (MainHistory_1.DBRECID) AS Positives, StatusTbl.Code,
             (SELECT        COUNT(DBRECID) AS Expr1
              FROM            MainHistory
              WHERE        (REALDATE > CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 102)) AND         (REALDATE < CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 102))) AS TotalCalls
        FROM            MainHistory AS MainHistory_1 INNER JOIN
                         StatusTbl ON MainHistory_1.STATUS = StatusTbl.Status
        GROUP BY MainHistory_1.REALDATE, StatusTbl.Status, StatusTbl.Code
        HAVING        (StatusTbl.Code = 'P') AND (MainHistory_1.REALDATE > CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 102)) AND (MainHistory_1.REALDATE < CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 102))
```

My Matrix looks like this:

```
[REALDATE]| Weekly Totals

EXPR      | EXPR
```

where the expressions are

```
FORMAT(Code.CalcPerHour(Lookupset(FORMAT(Fields!REALDATE.Value,"Long       Date"),FORMAT(Fields!CallbackDate.Value,"Long Date"),Fields!DailyHours.Value,"Hours_DataSet"),SUM(Fields!Positives.Value)),"Fixed")

Sum(Sum(Fields!Positives.Value))/SUM(code.CalcPTD(Lookupset(FORMAT(Fields!REALDATE.Value,"Long Date"),FORMAT(Fields!CallbackDate.Value,"Long Date"),Fields!DailyHours.Value,"Hours_DataSet")))
```

My custom code is this:

```
PUBLIC SHARED FUNCTION CalcPerHour(Hours AS OBJECT, Totals AS OBJECT) AS DECIMAL
       DIM i AS INTEGER
       DIM PerHour AS DECIMAL
       FOR i=0 TO UBOUND(Hours)
       IF  CINT(Hours(i)) < > 0 THEN
             PerHour = PerHour + (CDEC(Totals)/CDEC(Hours(i)))
       END IF
       Next i
       RETURN PerHour
    END FUNCTION

    PUBLIC SHARED FUNCTION CalcPTD(LookupArray AS Array) AS DECIMAL
          DIM I AS INTEGER
          DIM Total AS DECIMAL
          Total = 0
             FOR i = 0 to UBOUND(LookupArray)
                 Total = Total + CDEC(LookupArray(i))
             NEXT i
          RETURN Total
   END FUNCTION
```

My Output is this:

```
12/01/2014 | 12/02/2014 | 12/03/2014 | 12/04/2014 | 12/05/2014 | Weekly totals|

1.63       | 1.79       | 1.75       | 1.59       | 1.41       | .87
```

The numbers corresponding to the days of the week are correct.

The number I should be getting for a total is

```
313/190.75 = 1.64
```

If I break it down and just look at the sum like this:

```
sum(Code.CalcPTD(Lookupset(FORMAT(Fields!REALDATE.Value,"Long Date"),FORMAT(Fields!CallbackDate.Value,"Long Date"),Fields!DailyHours.Value,"Hours_DataSet")))
```

I get the result of 352.50

If I count the number of items like this:

```
Count(Code.CalcPTD(Lookupset(FORMAT(Fields!REALDATE.Value,"Long Date"),FORMA(Fields!CallbackDate.Value,"Long Date"),Fields!DailyHours.Value,"Hours_DataSet")))
```

I get the result of 9

If I count distinct the number of items like this:

```
CountDistinct(Code.CalcPTD(Lookupset(FORMAT(Fields!REALDATE.Value,"Long Date"),FORMAT(Fields!CallbackDate.Value,"Long Date"),Fields!DailyHours.Value,"Hours_DataSet")))
```

I get the expected 5

I tried to write code for a distinct sum but it wouldn't return a single result but a series of 5 corresponding to the days of the week and I have to display in a single cell.

Any help would be appreciated. I know its kinda complicated. If you have questions or need further clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer on my own. To get a grand total of a variable within a dataset you can use SUM(fields!VarName.Value,"DataSet") and it does it for you.